# Compiler showing 'pi' symbol on error

Tags: c++, coliru

I was testing some code on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), and I got a strange output. I went down the code and could reproduce it with this simple [piece of code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66324d1cbd4985bf):

```
int main()
{
    &pi;
}
```

The output on g++:

[image: output on g++]

clang:

[image: output on clang]

For instance, using just `pi` (without the address-of) shows the expected result:

```
main.cpp:3:5: error: 'pi' was not declared in this scope
    pi;
    ^
```

I tried to reproduce this on my machine, using g++ 4.9.2 and on others sites but I could not.

Is this some bug on this site, some config of these compilers ?

And why only using the address-of operator (`&`) shows this symbol ?

Comment: What happens if you put in `&tm;`? Do you get ™ showing up? If so your output is being interpreted as HTML.

Comment: @tadman According to this [site](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) ™ does not have an HTML "name" code, just an HTML number code: &#8482; This gives the expected [output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4b5054d82c00595).

Comment: ahaha this is hilarious

Comment: You think they might be using `innerHTML` to produce the output?

Comment: The HTML entity code for the trademark symbol is `&trade;`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No it doesn't.  Tags are being "sanitized" manually:                 `text += pre_open + line.replace(/</g, '&lt').replace(/>/g, '&gt') + pre_close;`

Comment: @Random832: That's what I get for browsing the DOM rather than viewing source. `(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻`

Comment: I almost got caught by that too, but since i _knew_ that tags work in pre, I looked for an alternate explanation. The DOM browser (I assume - I was using Firefox's built-in inspector) doesn't bother to show it as an entity because it is already showing it as a text node and therefore not as an element.

Comment: For the record, several people who have commented here know the Coliru maintainer. He is now aware of the issue. Thank you for raising it.

Comment: @Random832: Admittedly I was quite surprised that `<pre>` would inherently sanitise anything but `</pre>`, my conclusion for the split second between observation and posting the comment. But there's a cost/benefit ratio to checking these things out. I'm just glad I don't have to use HTML much any more: it's been a good decade since that was anywhere near the forefront of my profession.

Comment: Oh no! The Praetorians are here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Net_(1995_film)

Comment: Ohhh.... **please** try putting some Javascript in...

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It's a bug on the site, as the compiler's output is not properly escaped. The compiler should output `&pi;`, but that's valid HTML, producing the pi symbol you see.

Comment: can we get a live demo on somewhere like coliru to show this? :P

Comment: And quite often forgotten escaping turns out to be a security problem. So whenever one comes across it, it is polite to notify the site administrator about it.

Answer (score 50):

`&pi;` is html code for π. It looks like someone forgot to escape things properly.

Comment: 700 and a gold badge. What's really unpleasant is that this guy could have used that a lot more than me,

Comment: @DavidRicherby - rep is overrated, and doesn't put food on the table.